# Debug technique for debugging an unusual memory leak

Tags: windows, debugging, resource-leak

I have a windows application (legacy) that leaks a lot of memory. It does not leak private bytes, I only see with process explorer that it keeps loading from time to time many instances of the same (topically) windows dll-s.

Is there a tool I can use to "trap" the moments when dll-s are being mapped to the process space so that I can track that (with the application symbols) to the source code ?

Comment: In Process Monitor, you get the stack trace of every recorded action, so you can see who opened some file. I'm not sure this is useful in your case, because I don't think the DLLs need to actually be opened again if they are already loaded - but it's worth a try.

Comment: How can I specify in procmon that I want to watch opening of file "iologgingmsg.dll" for example ?

Comment: Define a filter which includes, say: `Path contains iologgingmsg.dll`. If you get too much noise, you can try to add a filter like `Operation is CreateFile`.

Comment: Yes, I saw you are right

Comment: @eran you can post an answer if you want, that solved my problem :-)

Comment: Happy to hear that worked! For completeness and rep, posted as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Process Monitor, you get the stack trace of every recorded action, so you can see who opened some file. Define a filter which includes, say: `Path contains iologgingmsg.dll`. If you get too much noise, you can try to add a filter like `Operation is CreateFile`.